# .net EF Unable to seed complete data using migration

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I'm trying to seed a few

```
context.Wishlists.AddOrUpdate(
            w => w.Name,
            new Wishlist
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "My First Wishlist",
                Invitees = new List<Invitee> {
                    new Invitee { Id = 1, FirstName = "Super", LastName = "Man", Email = "test@test.com" },
                    new Invitee { Id = 2, FirstName = "Super", LastName = "Bitch", Email = "test2@test2.com" }
                },
                Status = WishlistStatuses.Active,
                Items = new List<Item> { 
                    new Item { Id = 1, Name = "TestItem1", Status = ItemStatuses.Active, Store = "Toys R Us", Description = "Buy the brown one", SuggestedPrice = 100 },
                    new Item { Id = 2, Name = "TestItem2", Status = ItemStatuses.Active },
                    new Item { Id = 3, Name = "TestItem3", Status = ItemStatuses.Reserved }
                },
                Event = new Event { Id = 1, Name = "Shower", When = DateTime.Now, Location = "Here" },
                DateCreated = DateTime.Now
            }
        );

        // if admin user not created
        if (!context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == "Admin"))
        {
            var userStore = new UserStore<User>(context);
            var userManager = new UserManager<User>(userStore);
            var user = new User
            {
                UserName = "Admin",
                FirstName = "John",
                LastName = "Doe",
                Email = "admin@admin.com",
                Wishlist = context.Wishlists.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1),
                DateCreated = DateTime.Now
            };

            userManager.Create(user, "password");
        }
```

The problem is user.Wishlist is always null no matter what I do. User model inherits from IdentityUser. All the other fields are good. I'm going crazy with this migration stuff. DBInitializer was so much simpler.

Also when I try to re update-database I get a problem with datetime2 and can't update anything. It will only not show the datetime2 error when I comment out everything in the seed.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my datetime2 problem using c.DateTime(storeType: "datetime2", nullable: false) in my CreateTable code.